# How can I order a column of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have created a matrix out of two vectors

```
x<-c(1,118,3,220)
y<-c("A","B","C","D")
z<-c(x,y)
m<-matrix(z,ncol=2)
```

Now I want order the second row, but it doesn't work properly.
I tried:

```
m[order(m[,2]),]
```

The order should be 1,3,118,220, but it shows 1,118,220,3

Comment: Your second statement `y<-c(A,B,C,D)` does not execute.  Do you have variables called A,B,C and D?

Comment: Sorry, it´s edited! I forgot to use the quote sign in the example above!

Answer (score 1):

The matrix can only hold one class which in this case would be character since you have `"A","B","C","D"`.

So if still want to order the rows in matrix you need to subset the first column convert it into numeric, use `order` and then use them to reorder rows.

```
m[order(as.numeric(m[, 1])), ]

#    [,1]  [,2]
#[1,] "1"   "A" 
#[2,] "3"   "C" 
#[3,] "118" "B" 
#[4,] "220" "D"
```

Since you have data with mixed data types why not store them in dataframe instead ?

```
x<-c(1,118,3,220)
y<-c("A","B","C","D")
df <- data.frame(x,y)
df[order(df[,1]),]

#    x y
#1   1 A
#3   3 C
#2 118 B
#4 220 D
```